# C# Print Bitmap in landscape mode

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, printdocument

I'm trying to print a Bitmap in landscape mode, but I've run into a few problems.

My code is currently:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument doc = new  System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
doc.PrintPage += doc_PrintPage;
doc.Print();
```

The event is as follows:

```
   void doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(extendedWebBrowser.Width, extendedWebBrowser.Height);
        NativeMethods.GetImage(extendedWebBrowser, bitmap, Color.White);
        e.PageSettings.Landscape = true;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
```

However no matter what I do it's never printed in landscape mode. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: doc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true; before the print?

Comment: _"However no matter what I do"_ - What have you tried?